# How to save Images that are dowloaded WebView in android

Tags: android, webview

On loading the image from the url in `WebView` I want to store but it doesn't store.

This is my code.

```
Uri uri="http://202.87.34.17/MobileDetect/Wallpaper/Wallpaper_01.jpg";
widget29=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.widget29);
widget29.loadUrl(IMAGE);

save();

try{
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    OutputStream fOut = null;
    File file = new File(path, "/sdcard"+IMAGE_FILENAME+".jpg");
    fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
    Bitmap mBitmap = null;
    mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
    fOut.flush();
    fOut.close();

    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
            file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(),file.getName());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: what prob u rgeeting?pls paste logcat to review properly

Comment: Please try to format your code a bit next time. What is the `save()` method doing?

Comment: Where do you instantiate your bitmap?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but perhaps you need to wait until the image has downloaded before you call the save function? I'm not that experienced with Android, so I dont know if it continues instantly or it waits until the image is complete before the code continues.

But thats where I would look. Perhaps you can add some "callback" or raise some kinda event when "image download done".

Does this make any sense?